# How can I find the generators of $\mathbb C[t]$ as a $\mathbb C[t+t^2]$ module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

For every $f(t)=a_nt^n+...+a_1t+a_0$ how can i write this as $r_1g_1(t)+...+r_mg_m(t)$ for $r_i\in\mathbb C[t]$ and $g_i\in\mathbb C[t+t^2]$? I’m finding it impossible to find any $r_i$ and $g_i$ for a given polynomial like $f(t)=3t^5-2t^4+t^3-6$, so I’m not sure how to find $r_i$ such that they work for every polynomial. Is there even a way?

I’m trying to solve a larger problem which is to show that $\mathbb C[t]$ is integral over $\mathbb C[t+t^2]$, which our lecturer has shown how to do for other examples, and firstly finds the generators

Comment: The minimal polynomial of $t$ is monic of degree $2$ so $\mathbb C[t]=\mathbb C[t+t^2]+t \mathbb C[t+t^2]$.

Comment: We haven’t learnt about that. Is there another way I can show it? How would you write $t^3+1$ with those generators?

Comment: @Loobear23 I would write it as $$(1-(t+t^2)) +t(t+t^2+1)$$It's not that difficult. Clearly the $1$ comes from $\Bbb C[t^2+t]$, and $t^3$ comes from $t\Bbb C[t^2+t]$ (there are no odd-degree elements in $\Bbb C[t^2+t]$). After that, just fill in whatever you need to make all the other terms disappear. Of course, I'm not saying that it is easy in general. But this one was not particularly challenging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1,t$ suffices for a basis of $\Bbb C[t]$ as a $\Bbb C[t+t^2]$ module. You can prove this by induction on the degree of a polynomial: the base case of degree zero and degree one are obvious, so let $d>1$ and assume that you've shown that every polynomial of degree $d-1$ or less can be written as a $f(t^2+t)+g(t^2+t)t$. If $p$ is of degree $d$ with top term $at^d$, then $p-at^{d-2}(t^2+t)$ and $at^{d-2}$ are of lower degree and can be written appropriately by the induction hypothesis. So $at^{d-2}(t^2+t)$ can as well, and therefore $p=(p-at^{d-2}(t^2+t))+at^{d-2}(t^2+t)$ can be written as a $\Bbb C[t^2+t]$-linear combination of $1$ and $t$.

Alternatively, one can check that $\Bbb C[t]=\Bbb C[t^2+t][t]$, and $t$ satisfies the degree-two monic polynomial $X^2+X-(t^2+t)$, which is a direct proof of integrality.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense

Comment: @Loobear23 Glad to help. If that's resolved your difficulties, please consider accepting the answer. If not, please let me know if there's something missing.

Comment: Actually, how is $at^{d-2}(t^2+t)$ written in terms of the generators $t$ and $1$?

Comment: @Loobear23 $at^{d-2}$ is of degree less than $d$, so we can apply the induction hypothesis. Multiplying by $t^2+t$ preserves the desired property.